# How to include only user actions in combobox actionListener?

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have a JCombobox that populates at runtime, and repopulates based on other actions on the form.  The issue is that I only want the actionListener to be triggered by user mouse/keyboard clicks.  Unfortunately, the actionListener is triggered by the programatic clearing/loading of the combobox.

My attempt to circumvent this issue was to check to see if the control has focus, which will be the only way the user can manipulate it directly and will never be the case when other controls clear/load the contents of it.  Unfortunately, the `hasFocus()` portion always returns null.

Here is a stripped-down example of my form, containing only the issue:

```
package newProj;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class hasFocusTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    public static String DBurl; 
    private JComboBox<?> cmbEquipSpec;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hasFocusTest window = new hasFocusTest();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public hasFocusTest() {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void populateSpec(DefaultComboBoxModel<String> Speclist) {

        Speclist.removeAllElements();
        Speclist.addElement("1");
        Speclist.addElement("2");
        Speclist.addElement("3");
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 280, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.frame.setFocusable(false);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setBounds(10, 11, 240, 140);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JLayeredPane p_1 = new JLayeredPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Define Function", null, p_1, null);

        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> Speclist = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
        populateSpec(Speclist);

        cmbEquipSpec = new JComboBox<String>(Speclist);
        cmbEquipSpec.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                boolean sFocus = false;

                try {
                        sFocus = cmbEquipSpec.hasFocus();
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

                }

                System.out.println(sFocus);
                System.out.println("cmbEquipSpec: " + cmbEquipSpec);
            }
        });
        cmbEquipSpec.setEditable(true);
        cmbEquipSpec.setBounds(10, 31, 64, 20);
        p_1.add(cmbEquipSpec);

        JLabel lblEquipSpec = new JLabel("Equip Spec");
        lblEquipSpec.setBounds(15, 11, 74, 14);
        p_1.add(lblEquipSpec);
        p_1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If I change that middle portion to:

```
    Component sFocus = null;

try {
        sFocus = frame.getFocusOwner();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

}
```

Then it tells me that the component with focus is clearly different than the one that is clicked.

Component clicked:
`javax.swing.JComboBox[,10,31,64x20,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=4194632,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=true,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=3]`

Component with focus:
`javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$1[,0,0,44x20,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$EditorBorder@1d04923d,flags=8388904,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=9,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]`

I'm pretty new to this, it makes no sense to me why the combobox I'm clicking isn't the one with focus.  But, to re-iterate, this is my attempt at a solution.  If there is a way to exclude programatic actions from the actionListener then this would achieve my goal as well.  I believe.

Comment: `Unfortunately, the actionListener is triggered by the programatic clearing/loading of the combobox.` - then remove the ActionListener before clearing/loading the combo box and that add the listener back after the values have been loaded. Also, don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: I didn't consider that!  I'll try it.  As for the `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`, Eclipse does that automatically so I didn't question it.  I will look into that aspect, thank you very much.

Comment: Worked, after some troubleshooting.  If you make that an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the actionListener is triggered by the programatic clearing/loading of the combobox.

1. remove the ActionListener from the combo box
2. clear and reload the items of the combo box
3. add the ActionListener back to the combo box